# Hide select all checkbox when search data not in list of ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown version ^0.3.8 in my Angular project v11.It's working fine except one condition which occur when-

1- open select dropdown and search random thing which is not in list like 'xxxx'.

In this scenario it show select all button which is quite confusing. It's give impression of selecting all value which are present in list.
If anyhow I can hide this checkbox please tell me.
Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: please provide minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: I don't think there is any need of code details you can see this everywhere